# Inverse Fourier transform in two dimensions

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, fourier-transform, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to evaluate the following inverse Fourier transform:

$$\frac{1}{4 \pi^2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(\bar{k}, \bar{l}) e^{\iota( \bar{k} \bar{X}+\bar{l} \bar{Y})} d \bar{k} d \bar{l}$$

where $\bar{k}$ and $\bar{l}$ are real. I'm thinking of first integrating with respect to $\bar{k}$. To do that, I'm deforming the contour in complex $\bar{k}$ plane and then I'll apply the Residue theorem.
When I'm finding the poles of $f(\bar{k}, \bar{l})$, what value I should choose for $\bar{l}$ ?

Comment: What do you mean? You can't choose $\overline{l}$. The first integral will be a function of $\overline{l}$.

Comment: Thanks Tomasliam for the comment. The thing I'm concerned about is that I can't decouple my integrand as a product of two functions of $\bar{k}$ alone and $\bar{l}$ alone. How should I proceed in this case? Should I treat one complex variable as constant while evaluating the integral with respect to another variable?

Comment: Yes, you should